# Enable XML validation in CXF SOAP endpoint inside Camel route

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

I am developing a code-first SOAP service inside JBoss Fuse. I defined an interface `my.endpoint.Interface` with input and output classes. The wsdl is generated fine and the service is working. The endpoint is handled by CXF which invokes my Camel routes.

Versions:
JBoss Fuse 6.2.1
Apache Camel 2.15.1
Apache CXF 3.0.4

This is the configuration of my bundle:

```
<blueprint>

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="myEndpoint"
         address="/my/"
         serviceClass="my.endpoint.Interface">
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

    <camelContext>

        <route>
            <from uri="cxf:bean:myEndpoint" />
            <to uri="bean:doProcess" />
        </route>

    </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

I would like to apply XML validation using an XSD to the incoming payloads.

**How do I configure CXF in this particular environment?**

---

I didn't find out where to specify the XSD `CxfEndpointConfigurer` interface:

```
<!-- blueprint file -->
<from uri="cxf:bean:myEndpoint?cxfEndpointConfigurer=configurer" />

// java file
@Override
public void configureServer(Server server) {
    // where do I set XSD in here?
}
```

---

Configuring the `cxfEndpoint` in blueprint file raises an Exception at runtime

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="readingsEndpoint"
                 address="/readings/"
                 serviceClass="my.endpoint.Interface">
    <cxf:schemaLocations>
        <schemaLocation>classpath:my/endpoint/schema1.xsd</schemaLocation>
    </cxf:schemaLocations>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Does not work, raising the following exception:

```
Unable to start blueprint container for bundle my.bundle/0.0.0.SNAPSHOT
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.RecipeBuilder.getValue(RecipeBuilder.java:355)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.RecipeBuilder.getValue(RecipeBuilder.java:334)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.RecipeBuilder.createBeanRecipe(RecipeBuilder.java:278)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.RecipeBuilder.createRecipe(RecipeBuilder.java:110)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.RecipeBuilder.createRepository(RecipeBuilder.java:93)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.getRepository(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:481)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:328)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:269)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:294)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:263)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:253)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1127)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:696)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:484)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4429)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2100)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.updateBundle(Felix.java:2412)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.update(BundleImpl.java:994)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.dev.watch.BundleWatcher.run(BundleWatcher.java:120)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.dev:2.4.0.redhat-621084]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_101]
```

Answer (score 1):

In my contract-first setup I enable schema validation in a blueprint context like so:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="cxfEndpoint" address="http://0.0.0.0:${cxf.port}/${application-path}" serviceClass="my.generated.service.Class" >
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

This should work for code first just as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your XSD is separate from the WSDL, i.e. a different file you can use the validator component.

```
<camelContext>

    <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:myEndpoint" />
        <to uri="validator:my/endpoint/schema1.xsd" />
        <to uri="bean:doProcess" />
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

You should probably also enclose that with a doTry/doCatch or add an error handler to your route or context.

To configure the cxf-endpoint to set the Exchange body to the actual soap:body you can to the following:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="readingsEndpoint"
             address="/readings/"
             serviceClass="my.endpoint.Interface">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD"/>
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Comment: At that point the body of the Exchange has already been unmarshalled to a POJO. Is there some configuration to tell CXF not to unmarshal and do it myself after validation?

Comment: I see. Yes, you can set the dataFormat-property to "PAYLOAD", I'll update my answer.